# How to use JDBC 2.1 in Java to connect to LDAP

Tags: java, jdbc, ldap

I downloaded JDBC 2.1 and added jdbcLdap.jar as well as ldap.jar in my class path ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/myvd/files/jdbc%20ldap%20bridge/jdbc%20ldap%20bridge%202.1/jdbc-ldap-2.1.zip/download ). I would like to use it in my java application to connect to an LDAP, though I have not found any examples or explanations on how to use it (only how to connect to an sql server).

Could someone here possibly give a hint ?

Answer (score 3):

The [reference for the JDBC-LDAP bridge](http://myvd.sourceforge.net/bridge.html) is located at the the MyVD site. I think you've missed looking at it; it is fairly comprehensive on how to create connections and issue commands against a LDAP server.